# Node js call function, that access mysql database and returns json result, multiple times

Tags: mysql, json, node.js

I'm new to Node.js. I have a function 'getFromDb' that accesses a mysql database and returns a json file with some data. What if I have an array of query data and I want to call the same function through a for loop to get a json file for each element of the array?

```
        var http = require('http');         

        http.createServer(function(req, res) {

            console.log('Receving request...');

            var callback = function(err, result) {
                res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + queryData+ '.json');
                res.writeHead(200, {
                    'Content-Type' : 'x-application/json'
                });
                console.log('json:', result);
                res.end(result);    
            };

        getFromDb(callback, queryData);}  
        ).listen(9999);

        function getFromDb(callback, queryData){
        var mysql = require('mysql');
            var connection = mysql.createConnection({
                host : 'localhost',
                user : 'xxxx',
                password : 'xxxx',
                database : 'xxxx',
                port: 3306
            });

            connection.connect();
            var json = '';
            var data = queryData + '%';
            var query = 'SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE POSTCODE LIKE "' + data + '"';
            connection.query(query, function(err, results, fields) {
                if (err)
                    return callback(err, null);

                console.log('The query-result is: ', results);

                // wrap result-set as json
                json = JSON.stringify(results);

                /***************
                * Correction 2: Nest the callback correctly!
                ***************/
                connection.end();
                console.log('JSON-result:', json);
                callback(null, json);
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the async library for node for this. That library has many functions that make asynchronous programming in NodeJS much easier. The "each" or "eachSeries" functions would work. "each" would make all the calls to mysql at once time, while "eachSeries" would wait for the previous call to finish. You could use that inside your getFromDB method for your array.

See:
https://github.com/caolan/async#each

```
var http = require('http'),
  async = require('async');

http.createServer(function(req, res) {

    console.log('Receving request...');

    var callback = function(err, result) {
      res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + queryData+ '.json');
      res.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type' : 'x-application/json'
      });
      console.log('json:', result);
      res.end(result);
    };

    getFromDb(callback, queryData);}
).listen(9999);

function getFromDb(callback, queryData){
  var mysql = require('mysql');
  var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host : 'localhost',
    user : 'xxxx',
    password : 'xxxx',
    database : 'xxxx',
    port: 3306
  });

  connection.connect();

  var arrayOfQueryData = ["query1", "query2", "query3", "query4", "query5"];
  var jsonResults = [];

  async.each(arrayOfQueryData, function (queryData, cb) {
    var data = queryData + '%';
    var query = 'SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE POSTCODE LIKE "' + data + '"';
    connection.query(query, function(err, results, fields) {
      if (err)
        return cb(err);
      console.log('The query-result is: ', results);
      // wrap result-set as json
      var json = JSON.stringify(results);
      console.log('JSON-result:', json);
      jsonResults.push(json);
      cb();
    });

  }, function (err) {
    connection.end();
    // callbacks from getFromDb
    if (err) {
      callback(err);
    }
    else {
      callback(null,jsonResults);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: So you think i should use something like this: var arrayOfQueryData = new Array();
arrayOfQueryData = ["query1", "query2", "query3", "query4", "query5"];
async = require("async");
async.each(arrayOfQueryData, getFromDb, function(err){
  console.log(err);
 });  in getFromDb function?

Comment: I don't like posting untested code, but that should give you the idea.

Answer (score 1):

use async module. it is the best one. If u dont want to add new module try following;

```
var count = 0;

array.forEach(function(element) { //array of the data that is to be used to call mysql
    ++count; //increase counter for each service call
    async.db.call(element, callback); //the async task
}
var data = [];
function callback(err, resp) {
    --count;//subtract for each completion
    data.push(resp)
    if(count == 0) { //return data when all is complete
        return data;
    }
}
```

I would recommend the async module though. it is very good practice and useful.

Comment: Can you give me more hints for using async module, related to code given in the question, please?