# Heroku - NodeJS - Send json with data from postgres database

Tags: node.js, postgresql, heroku

I'm starting with Heroku and NodeJS and Postgres database.

I have several tables named table1, table2, table3, ...table27.
All tables have the same structure 10 columns.

I'm trying to build a webservice to send as json all data from these tables.

I tried several ways, usync async modules or without but without success. I fected some unwanted data (basically, database structure). For example:

> JSON-result:
>   {"command":"SELECT","rowCount":0,"oid":null,"rows":[],"fields":[{"name":"id","tableID":945497,"columnID":1,"dataTypeID":23,"dataTypeSize":4,"dataTypeModifier":-1,"format":"text"},{"name":"code_event","tableID":945497,"columnID":2,"dataTypeID":23,"dataTypeSize":4,"dataTypeModifier":-1,"format":"text"},{"name":"version","tableID":945497,"columnID":3,"dataTypeID":23,"dataTypeSize":4,"dataTypeModifier":-1,"format":"text"},{"name":"used","tableID":945497,"columnID":4,"dataTypeID":23,"dataTypeSize":4,"dataTypeModifier":-1,"format":"text"},{"name":"reference1","tableID":945497,"columnID":5,"dataTypeID":1043,"dataTypeSize":-1,"dataTypeModifier":104,"format":"text"},{"name":"reference2","tableID":945497,"columnID":6,"dataTypeID":1043,"dataTypeSize":-1,"dataTypeModifier":104,"format":"text"},{"name":"reference3","tableID":945497,"columnID":7,"dataTypeID":1043,"dataTypeSize":-1,"dataTypeModifier":104,"format":"text"},{"name":"reference4","tableID":945497,"columnID":8,"dataTypeID":1043,"dataTypeSize":-1,"dataTypeModifier":104,"format":"text"},{"name":"reference5","tableID":945497,"columnID":9,"dataTypeID":1043,"dataTypeSize":-1,"dataTypeModifier":104,"format":"text"},{"name":"label1","tableID":945497,"columnID":10,"dataTypeID":1043,"dataTypeSize":-1,"dataTypeModifier":104,"format":"text"},{"name":"label2","tableID":945497,"columnID":11,"dataTypeID":1043,"dataTypeSize":-1,"dataTypeModifier":104,"format":"text"},{"name":"label3","tableID":945497,"columnID":12,"dataTypeID":1043,"dataTypeSize":-1,"dataTypeModifier":104,"format":"text"},{"name":"label4","tableID":945497,"columnID":13,"dataTypeID":1043,"dataTypeSize":-1,"dataTypeModifier":104,"format":"text"},{"name":"label5","tableID":945497,"columnID":14,"dataTypeID":1043,"dataTypeSize":-1,"dataTypeModifier":104,"format":"text"},{"name":"export_action","tableID":945497,"columnID":15,"dataTypeID":1043,"dataTypeSize":-1,"dataTypeModifier":54,"format":"text"}],"_parsers":[null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null],"rowAsArray":false}

I tried these code: 
[Node js call function, that access mysql database and returns json result, multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27903992/node-js-call-function-that-access-mysql-database-and-returns-json-result-multi)

How can I get a proper json with following data?
{table1: {row1, row2...}, table2:{row1,row2...}....}

Comment: Have you tried [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) ;)

Comment: Do you mean `{ table1: [{row1}, {row2}, ...], table2: [{row1}, {row2}, ...]}, ...}`?

Comment: That would be closer to the data you are already getting. Then you would just add the results of `JSON-result.fields` for each table call from an async function to one object.

Comment: Thanks. pg-promise seems to do the job :-)